# Google Maps API Places search box not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-places-api

I have been following the [Google Maps API Places search box example](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/places-searchbox) in order to create a map with a search box.

Both the map and the search box appear just fine.

The problem is that typing into the search box does nothing. No dropdown, no autocomplete, and pressing enter does not initiate a search.

Have I missed something?

HTML:

```
<script src='//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometr‌​y,places' type='text/javascript'></script>

<input id='pac-input' class='controls' type='text' placeholder='Search'>

<div id='map_search' style='width: 100%; height: 30rem;'>
```

JavaScript:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  var mapstyle = [{"featureType":"water","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#e9e9e9"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"landscape","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":17}]},{"featureType":"road.highway","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":29},{"weight":0.2}]},{"featureType":"road.arterial","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":18}]},{"featureType":"road.local","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"featureType":"poi","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f5f5f5"},{"lightness":21}]},{"featureType":"poi.park","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#dedede"},{"lightness":21}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.stroke","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"color":"#ffffff"},{"lightness":16}]},{"elementType":"labels.text.fill","stylers":[{"saturation":36},{"color":"#333333"},{"lightness":40}]},{"elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"off"}]},{"featureType":"transit","elementType":"geometry","stylers":[{"color":"#f2f2f2"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"transit.station","elementType":"labels.icon","stylers":[{"visibility":"on"},{"hue":"#2185d0"},{"lightness":19}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.fill","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":20}]},{"featureType":"administrative","elementType":"geometry.stroke","stylers":[{"color":"#fefefe"},{"lightness":17},{"weight":1.2}]}
  ];

  function initialize() {
    var peckham = new google.maps.LatLng(51.4714, -0.0625);

    // Map search
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_search'), {
      center: peckham,
      zoom: 14,
      styles: mapstyle,
      scrollwheel: false
    });

    // Create the search box and link it to the UI element.
    var input = document.getElementById('pac-input');
    var searchBox = new google.maps.places.SearchBox(input);
    map.controls[google.maps.ControlPosition.TOP_LEFT].push(input);

    // Bias the SearchBox results towards current map's viewport.
    map.addListener('bounds_changed', function() {
      searchBox.setBounds(map.getBounds());
    });

    var markers = [];

    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var service = new google.maps.places.PlacesService(map);

    // Listen for the event fired when the user selects a prediction and retrieve
    // more details for that place.
    searchBox.addListener('places_changed', function() {
      var places = searchBox.getPlaces();

      if (places.length == 0) {
        return;
      }

      // Clear out the old markers.
      markers.forEach(function(marker) {
        marker.setMap(null);
      });
      markers = [];

      // For each place, get the icon, name and location.
      var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
      places.forEach(function(place) {
        var icon = {
          url: place.icon,
          size: new google.maps.Size(71, 71),
          origin: new google.maps.Point(0, 0),
          anchor: new google.maps.Point(17, 34),
          scaledSize: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
        };

        // Create a marker for each place.
        markers.push(new google.maps.Marker({
          map: map,
          icon: icon,
          title: place.name,
          position: place.geometry.location
        }));

        // Show infowindow
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function(evt) {
          service.getDetails({
            placeId: this.placeId
          }, (function(marker) {
            return function(place, status) {
              if (status === google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK) {
                infowindow.setContent('<div><strong>' + place.name + '</strong><br>' +
                  'Place ID: ' + place.place_id + '<br>' +
                  place.formatted_address + '</div>');
                infowindow.open(map, marker);
              }
            }
          }(marker)));
        });

        if (place.geometry.viewport) {
          // Only geocodes have viewport.
          bounds.union(place.geometry.viewport);
        } else {
          bounds.extend(place.geometry.location);
        }
      });
      map.fitBounds(bounds);
    });
  }
</script>
```

Comment: How are you including the API?  Are you [loading the places library](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/places#loading_the_library)?  The posted code [works for me](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j4am7js9/), please provide a [Minimal, Complete, Tested and Readable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that demonstrates the issue.

Comment: Yes, I am loading the places library in the head section: `<script src='//maps.google.com/maps/api/js?v=3.13&amp;sensor=false&amp;libraries=geometry,places' type='text/javascript'></script>`

Comment: Please include that in your question, the posted code doesn't exhibit the described issue ([working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/geocodezip/j4am7js9/))

Comment: Thanks. Added that to my question. This is weird. It does not seem to be working in my Rails app. Might there be some conflict somewhere? Everything else seems to work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the issue.

There was an autocomplete function elsewhere that was causing a conflict:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('search_address');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>

<script type='text/javascript'>
  function initialize() {
    var input = document.getElementById('listing_address');

    var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input);
  }

  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
```

Comment: Other solution that worked for me, maybe it will help someone.
You need to go to console.developers.google.com > to your project > dashboard.
there you need to enable Places.API